# What is the correct tf configuartion for RGBDSLAM?

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rgbdslamv2, rgbdslam-v2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to use RGBDSLAM with an initial ground_truth, to map the trajectory to my cordinate system.
Therefore I publish a tf from *map* to *ground_truth_frame* and set the parameter *config/ground_truth_frame_name* to *ground_truth_frame*.
But I still get the following Warning:
**"openni_camera" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame does not exist.  - Using Identity for Ground Truth (This message is throttled to 1 per 5 seconds)**

How can I set the pose for my initial Node?

edit: I use some kind of fake Camera to publish the Images from files, so there is actually noch openNI running.open

edit: As I can see from the openni_listener.cpp I need a tf from the bas_frame to some kind of depth_frame(I have no clue what this is) and also I need a tf from ground_truth_frame to openni_camera.
I dont know the meaning of these tfs...could someone please help me on this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239709/what-is-the-correct-tf-configuartion-for-rgbdslam?/) by [alubitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25835/alubitz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

New answer since I think I understood your problem now.

My suggestion (July 19) with the [static transform publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher) from */newmap* to */map* helps when you use the /tf transformations online. But you seem to use the saved trajectory. To have the trajectory affected you would need to do it as follows.

Use a static transform publisher from *yourbase* to *yoursensorframe* set to your known static offset (you call it ground truth). You can choose *yourbase* as you wish but *yoursensorframe* needs to be set to the same as the frame_id set in the rgbd image (I'd guess of the color image, but maybe depth).

Then set rgbdslam's parameter `base_frame_name` to *yourbase* and `fixed_frame_name` to *map* (or whatever else).

Then rgbdslam should make the first position of *yourbase* (i.e. the inverse offset as seen from the camera) to the position of *map*.

I hope this works. If not, the relevant code is in [the trajectory saving method](https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2/blob/indigo/src/graph_mgr_io.cpp#L614)

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0